# Mysql comments tag breaking my code (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO to prepare querys, but when I put # or -- (SQL commentaries) it still working (I know PDO won't disable it) how to make it stop? this comments break my whole code. (I want allow to use it but stop breaking)
Eg:
`SELECT * FROM something WHERE var=:var AND value=:value`
I just put # and this happens
`SELECT * FROM something WHERE var=:var# AND value=:value` only will check for var/:var
(Assume :var was user input using #)

Comment: Why not just name the parameter `:varnum` instead of using characters that will break the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your variables with single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM something WHERE var=':var#' AND value=':value'
```

Comment: I didn't know single quotes disable comments, Thanks