# Mysql PDO prepare to execute count (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Current I'm trying to query a COUNT(*) using user input, so I want to prepare it, but when I do it there are no response, also I made using this:
[Row count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/count-with-pdo) as example, (prepare and query) but they both seems to doesn't work. Why? theres no reason...

```
$count = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table WHERE senha='$senha' AND var='{$ar[$i]}'")->fetchColumn();
    if($count!=0){
        $q = $con->prepare("UPDATE $table SET value=':value' WHERE senha=':senha' AND var=':var'");
        $q->execute(array(':senha' => $senha, ':value' => $ar[$i+1], ':var' => $ar[$i]));
    }else{
        $q = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (id,senha,var,value) VALUES (NULL, ':senha', ':var', ':value')");
        $q->execute(array(':senha' => $senha, ':var' => $ar[$i], ':value' => $ar[$i+1]));
    }
```

When I were using his first example (using prepare not query passing values using array) didn't work at all, the query one return a number but does not work the `if` (`update` or `insert`) part I've tried a bunch of things and outputs, nothing worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not include single quote when you use parameters bind with PDO. so correct your UPDATE and INSERT query to followings:

```
$q = $con->prepare("UPDATE $table SET value=:value WHERE senha=:senha AND var=:var");
```

and

```
$q = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (id,senha,var,value) VALUES (NULL, :senha, :var, :value)");
```

Comment: Without single quotes they can use # or -- how to prevent this?

Comment: That will be taking care by PDO. That's the one of purpose of using PDO parameter bind actually :)

Comment: Weird, when I tried it seems to be commented hm, I'll try again. Thanks for answer (Accepted cause makes sense...)

Comment: you're welcome. please update here if you have any issue with it. I will try to answer

Comment: Assuming your answer, he is wrong in here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595970/mysql-comments-tag-breaking-my-code-php/11595984#11595984

Comment: Tested again, still commenting my whole code... You answered the question, but if you can help me with this I would appreciate

Comment: Also, it prevent from -- comment, but no from #

Comment: What values for the queries do you exactly have? The parameters should filter those any special characters for SQL. I wonder if you are having a problem with the first SELECT query? It isn't using parameters thus you need to sanitize values